# Illegal character with Blue J

Tags: java, variables, project, type-conversion, bluej

**Program**

```
public class Project_X
{
   public static void main(String[] args){

      byte x;
      int a=270;
      double b =128.128;

      System.out.println("int converted to byte");
      x=(byte) a;

      System.out.println("a and x "+ a +" "+x);
      System.out.println("double converted to int");

      a=(int) b;

      System.out.println("b and a "+ b +" "+a);
      System.out.println("n double converted to byte");

      x=(byte) b;

      System.out.println("b and x "+b +" "+x);
   }
}
```

**error get**

> illegal character:\160

Comment: im starting out and already a problem i can't figure out. help please

Comment: What line causes the error? And please post formatted code, not all left-justified code since that's hard to read.

Comment: I ran the above program and got no others

Comment: its like this
https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/q71/s720x720/995913_671908809489613_1659572467_n.jpg

im compiling it but it gives me that error i cant figure out.

Comment: `\u160` is the [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). Have you tried deleting and retyping the line?

Comment: ahhh.damn got it! thanks for the response everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copy-pasted the program code using a tool (probably a web browser) that includes "funky" symbols in copied text. E.g. the non-breaking space.

One way to expose these characters is the following:

1. Go to http://www.asciitohex.com/
2. Copy-paste your code into the input box
3. Click on convert
4. Copy paste text from "Html Entities" output on lower right corner
5. Remove all &nbsp;-s and other strange things from code

Comment: This is going to sound snarky, but it's meant to be a genuine suggestion: just don't to copy/paste code examples.

Answer (score 0):

`\u160` is the [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). Have you tried deleting and retyping the line?